# How to Color Part of Object Different From the Other With Texture Paint

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I'm an (almost complete) beginner at Blender and am stuck on this simple issue - I just need to color the bird's stomach (beige) different from the rest of his body (red).[image]

Notice the Angry Bird reference to the left.

I've switched over to texture paint mode, added another Material and am painting on the Body object, but nothing is happening.

[image]

Why not? How do I make the stomach beige and the rest of the body red in Blender 2.9?

[Link to file](https://pasteall.org/blend/2c042049ff7f40da95b14f22d6abb71c)

Comment: Please pack the textures into your Blend file using File > External Data > Pack Resources and upload it again. Having said that, there's a YT video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SddgOe1A7gU&list=PLsGl9GczcgBtNd8e8LhfylyK80elW6sOo&index=3) showing how to set up and texture paint a penguin which might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a 1-minute overview video I quickly recorded of how to do it!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v1C7SI9UYgP_7dFdcUpo8U-RD3PR5TkP/view?usp=sharing

On a high level, what you need to do is:

1. Make sure your object is "UV unwrapped"
2. Make an image texture
3. Assign that image texture to your material
4. You're good to go! You can now paint on either the Texture map directly, or your model

---

ONE IMPORTANT DETAIL: Make sure to hit alt+s to save your texture regularly. It is not saved automatically when you hit ctrl+s to save the blender file. I recommend packing textures into your blender file, as the other answer pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

In texture painting, you paint on an image texture. A material just references that image that has been painted. You're not actually painting the material. If you added a new material but didn't assign it to any parts of your mesh, it won't do anything.

Take a look at this video on texture painting basics, it's a good quick rundown and I think it addresses your question in a very clear way.

Texture Painting
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnRQhH3fEDY